# Animation Div simultaneous

Tags: jquery

I created two div with which I made a shift to the left of animation, by instruction:

```
    $(".secondo").animate({    
                left: "80px"
    }, "slow") 
$(".primo").animate({    
                left: "-22px"
}, "slow")
```

As you see:

http://jsfiddle.net/spvmamy5/

the two animations are not simultaneous.
I ask you to do an animation on the two div be simultaneous?

Comment: It's because the code in your fiddle has `duration` set to `1000`. If you actually execute the code in your question, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/spvmamy5/3/

Comment: Please follow as @RoryMcCrossan mention in comment and update in fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the code in your jsFiddle includes a `duration: 1000` parameter on only 1 of the animations. If you change the logic to that shown in your actual question it works fine.

Note however, that you can join both animations together, like this:

```
$(".secondo, .primo").animate({
    left: "-=32px"
}, "slow")
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/spvmamy5/6/)